Problem updating calendar event via iCalendar (.ics) in Gmail
I am encountering an issue while working with iCalendar (.ics) files in a system developed in Symfony. The goal is to allow users to create meetings and send an email with an .ics file attached so that participants can add the event to their calendars.
The event creation functionality works perfectly. On the first email, the .ics file is attached, and the event is correctly added to the Gmail calendar without issues.
However, when I try to update the event (by sending a new .ics with the same UID and updated values), Gmail does not update the existing event. It simply ignores the update. Even though the .ics file has the correct UID and adheres to RFC 5545, the event remains unchanged in Google Calendar. It seems that Gmail is fetching the event information from the already registered calendar entry instead of processing the new .ics file.
First .ics (event creation):
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Company Name//NONSGML Product Name//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20241006T140000
DTEND:20241006T150000
DTSTAMP:20240909T115350
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john@example.com
UID:715e82fa3b623c04f4eb343985dbbe7555a0be99@example.com
CREATED:20240909T115347
DESCRIPTION:Meeting 05
LAST-MODIFIED:20240909T115350
LOCATION:Auditorium
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Meeting 05
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Second .ics (event update, which doesn't apply):
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Company Name//NONSGML Product Name//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20241007T163000
DTEND:20241007T173000
DTSTAMP:20240909T115441
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john@example.com
UID:715e82fa3b623c04f4eb343985dbbe7555a0be99@example.com
CREATED:20240909T115347
DESCRIPTION:Meeting 05
LAST-MODIFIED:20240909T115441
LOCATION:Auditorium
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Meeting 05
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Behavior observed
In the first email with the .ics file, the event is added to the Gmail calendar as expected. In the second email, however, the event in the calendar is not updated. I suspect Gmail is ignoring the new file and relying on the already registered event in the calendar.
Interestingly, when I manually import the second .ics file through the Google Calendar settings (instead of relying on Gmail to process it), the event is updated correctly. This suggests that Gmail may be behaving differently from the calendar import feature.
Questions

What could be causing this issue? Is there anything else I should check in the .ics file?
Is there any specific behavior of Google Calendar when processing updates to events via Gmail?
Has anyone else encountered this kind of issue with event updates in Gmail/Google Calendar?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Since you're doing this over email, you may want to look at RFC 5546 .  Specifically, you may need to use METHOD:PUBLISH as REQUEST is specifically used for requesting a response from an ATTENDEE and you have none.
